# Team Foundation Server 2013 and Large SQL Tables

Tags: sql-server, team-foundation-server

I have a Windows 2008 R2 virtual machine running Team Foundation Server 2013 and MS SQL Server Express.  We are a small (<10 programmers) development shop and have 3-4 collections in TFS.  We stood this system up 1.5 months ago.  Today TFS stopped working with the error:

```
TF30042: The database is full. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.
```

Sure enough, upon investigation of the SQL tables that underpin TFS. I found one that had grown to over 10 GB, which is the limit for SQL Express.  Investigation of the error logs on the server confirms:

```
CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size     would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database.
```

The obvious solution is to move to SQL Server 2008, which we are doing.  However, I wanted to know if it is normal for TFS to create tables like this?  10 GB in six weeks?  Does anyone know how to clean or manage what goes into the SQL tables underlying TFS?  Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT

We are doing a small automated build and a few automated test runs on a continuous basis whenever someone checks in.  I have read at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/10/31/tfs-databases-growing-out-of-control.aspx that this can cause large SQL tables.  Does anyone know how to delete the unneeded data from this operation?

Comment: What's the size of the Tables? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database

Comment: We have been using TFS for a small team for years now, and we're at ~6 GB Database size, so there seems to be something wrong, unless your uploading tons of sourcecode or attachments of course

Comment: MichelZ - size of the table is just over 10300 KB.

Comment: Size of all tables??

Comment: There is one particularly table called dbo.tbl_Content that is just over 10 GB.  I would post a picture but SF won't let me until I have some rep.

Comment: You may want to monitor this one, he's trying to find a solution for that as well: https://mgrowan.wordpress.com/2014/04/02/need-help-tfs-tbl_content-table-and-database-growth-out-of-control/

Comment: Sorry to sound unhelpful, but have you considered moving away from TFS to a more useful version control system, like Git or even Subversion?

Comment: Matthew Skelton - We use git inside TFS.  To be honest we are taking advantage of hardly any of the TFS features (like automated building, which we never got working, we switched to team city).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to: https://mgrowan.wordpress.com/2014/04/02/need-help-tfs-tbl_content-table-and-database-growth-out-of-control/

> Update 4 April 2014: Something has happened overnight. I’m assuming
>   the workspace clean has caused it. We now have 115 GB space available!
>   What’s odd though is that the tbl_Content size has dropped that space.
>   What does that table have to do with workspaces? Some insights into
>   how this is working so we can manage our systems would be appreciated.

So, try to clean your Workspaces. The automatic build might leave some of them.
You can use the free [TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) to do this.

Comment: Do we know if this works with TFS 2013?  I think their website is currently down but their download link (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/70C4CAF6-40E5-4A46-AAFD-858544C3A7DD) advertises only up to TFS2008

Comment: I'm using them with TFS 2013, so yes. But there's a version specific to TFS 2013